# XmlReader (.net) returned 404 with RSS-link that Feedly reads ok

Tags: asp.net, .net, rss, xmlreader, feedly

```
   string RSSURL = "http://zakupki.gov.ru/tinyurl/6a6ae7ed-e77d-4572-b7ac-43856452b2f6";

        WebClient wclient = new WebClient(); //method 1
        string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString(RSSURL);
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(RSSData);


        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(RSSURL);//method 2. Both 404
```

It should be noted that the resource `zakupki.gov.ru` is very specific, with other channels these methods work well.
A few nuget libraries I've seen are also working through `xmlReader`. That is, they can not solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this library helped me https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeHollow.FeedReader/
1234567